# React-router redirect is looping over components in Meteorjs

Tags: redirect, meteor, reactjs, path, react-router

I am experimenting on custom admin view page and do have one question about the behavior.

The current logic at the moment is:

- If the user in not authenticated and tries to visit **/admin-panel** or its children he/she gets redirected to **/&** login page.
- If user in logged in and visits **/&** (login page) he/she gets redirected to **/admin-panel**

The problem is when the user is lodded in and is on **/admin-panel** and reloads the page the following occurs:

1. First **/&** page loads
2. Then **/&** redirects user to **/admin-panel**
   If the user was on or **/admin-panel/child_component**  after reload he/she will be on **/admin-panel** and will have to navigate again to **/child_component**

Can you please explain what is the cause of current behavior and if there is some way to make user stay on the page the reload was initiated and can the constant redirection be avoided?

The login page **/&**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker'

class Backdoor extends Component {

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Collecting user input
    const self = this;
    const email = $(event.target).find('[name=email]').val();
    const password = $(event.target).find('[name=password]').val();

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err) {
        browserHistory.push('admin-panel');
    });
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
      if (Meteor.user()) {
        browserHistory.push('/admin-panel')
      } else if(!Meteor.user()) {
            browserHistory.push('/&')
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (

    // Login form
    );
  }
}

export default Backdoor;
```

React-router paths':

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>

    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <Router path='about' component={About} />
    </Route>

    <Route path='&' component={Backdoor} />

    <Route path='admin' component={AdminPanel}>
      <Router path='/admin/admin_component' component={AdminChild} />
    </Route>

  </Router>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I've got rid of **/&** route and now the Admin Authentication routes look like that:

```
const newRoutes = (

 <Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <Router path='about' component={About} />
  </Route>
  <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} >
    <Route path='/admin/admin_child' component={AdminChild} />\
    // Feel free to add more routes here
  </Route>
</Router>
);
```

So inside the admin route you define **if** statement for checking if user is logged in. The hole component looks like that:

```
export class Admin extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
      if(!Meteor.userId()) {
            browserHistory.push('/admin')
      }
    })
  }

  render(props) {
    if (Meteor.userId()){
      return (<div><JuliaNav />{this.props.children}</div>)
    } else {
      return (<div><Backdoor /></div>)
    }
  }
}
```

So if the admin is not logged in React returns log-in form, and if he/she is logged in the component returns AdminNavigation for further interaction with data.
Tracker checks the state of user and if the button Log Off (inside AdminNavigation) will be clicked the page will be reloaded (with browserHistory.push) and AdminNavigation component will be replaced with the log-in form.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your routes file in the following way:

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <Route path='about' component={About} />
      <Route path='&' component={Backdoor} />
      <Route path='admin' component={Admin} />
      <Route path='admin/admin_component' component={AdminChild} />
      <Route path='admin/admin_panel' component={AdminPanel} />
    </Route>
 </Router>
);
```

So we got rid of the nested "Router" components that you had in there and added a "AdminPanel" component.

One of the things I usually do is assign an IndexRoute to my apps. You can look that up and it might provides some benefit, I didn't add it in since you didn't have it in your code.

Another efficiency (IMO) is to nest your admin routes as such:

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <Router path='about' component={About} />
      <Route path='&' component={Backdoor} />
      <Route path='admin' component={Admin}>
        <Route path='/admin_component' component={AdminChild} />
        <Route path='/admin_panel' component={AdminPanel} />
      </Route>
   </Route>
 </Router>
);
```

Note that the admin panel is nested in the admin route so to get there it would be /admin/admin_panel. Also, I would use "" quotes instead of ''.

Comment: thank you a for the time you have dedicating on this case, I do appreciate a lot. I did tested inside my environment your suggestions from above and in first case It kind of worked for me, but I had troubles with controlling user authentication on each route. And came up with probably a way easier way I will present it bellow.